# is there any easy/convenient way to find where a variable is defined in Lua, when using Lua as an embedded language into, say c++?

Tags: c++, lua

I'm working on Lua scripts, which are embedded into c++. I found it is really not convenient to find the original definition of a variable, which is used in Lua and which is more than likely defined in c++. For example,

```
function Guidance.get_turn_lanes(way,data)
  local psv_fw, psv_bw = get_psv_counts(way,data)      
  local turn_lanes_fw, turn_lanes_bw = Tags.get_forward_backward_by_key(way,data,'turn:lanes') 
  local vehicle_lanes_fw, vehicle_lanes_bw = Tags.get_forward_backward_by_key(way,data,'vehicle:lanes') 

  return process_lanes(turn_lanes_fw,vehicle_lanes_fw,psv_bw,psv_fw) or turn_lanes,   -- where to find the definition of variable turn_lanes? 
         process_lanes(turn_lanes_bw,vehicle_lanes_bw,psv_fw,psv_bw) or turn_lanes    
end
```

Now I use the Find in Project tab of Atom, to search for the keyword `turn_lanes` to try to locate where it is defined. I was wondering, is there any better way to find the original definition of `turn_lanes`? Moreover, how are c++ and lua talking to each other in general? (I hope the second question is not too naive or too general.)

Comment: `git grep "turn_lanes"` would be *my* go-to.

Comment: Google for `Zero Brain Lua` :) This IDE will probably help you.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering, how did Lua interpreter knows where to find these strange variables?

Comment: They're probably global variables defined by the embedding program or some module.

Answer (score 0):

## Yes and No.

Lua doesn't really remember where a variable is defined (nor does it care). However, there's a few tricks you can try, depending on what exactly you're looking for.

### `__newindex` metamethod

You could, for one, attach a `__newindex` metamethod to `_G`, which prints some output every time a new global variable is defined. Place at some place where it gets executed before anything else in your script. You can use `debug.getinfo` to figure out where you are in the call stack.

Maybe you can use the `-l` flag to load this hack before any other module can be loaded (and sneak in a global variable before you've installed your hook)

### `debug.getinfo`

If you're looking for a Lua function, you can use `debug.getinfo` to figure out where the function was defined. This works less well for code that was compiled without debug information using `luac -s`

### External tools

In many cases it's just easier to use an external tool to find things in code. The comments under your question mention some good choices:

- ZeroBrane (A Lua IDE)
- git grep (In case you're using git)